# Scalable Simplistic Key Value Database

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

I've been looking into different key-value databases (Mongo, Cassandra, etc.) and am trying to figure out which is best for speed and efficiency for very simple data storage. It seems like in a lot of cases it is key-value, but the value is something more complicated. I just want the key to be a string (hash) and the value to be an integer value so I do not need a lot of the extra stuff these databases have. For instance I am not storing documents, json, or anything complicated at all besides the string key and the integer value.

My current (MySQL) database has ~1 billion records and I am looking to move this to a more appropriate environment so I can get it to 1 trillion+ records and not have the scaling and performance issues that MySQL will have at that point (plus MySQL is unnecessary if it is very simplistic key-value anyways).

So, the question is, what database is best fit for maximum performance/scaling ability for a very very simplistic key-value database structure?

Comment: You'll need more metrics. How big are your keys, are they really just integers (32 bit?). Most important is how many write and reads, what's you're average load, what's your peak load.

Comment: Right now the keys are md5 hashes. However I can choose whatever hashing algorithm is most efficient when building this database (so it can be integers if that makes a difference). The database will be built to its 1-10 trillion records and then will primarily be read only after that. Right now the current database is processing only 5-10k queries/second, although that number might go up to a number closer to 50k-100k queries/second. As it is right now my load is very low (although everything is currently on SSDs which might not be economically practical for a bigger DB).